# Почему переменная не записывается в LS?

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Есть код:

```
<script>
        var colorPicker = document.getElementById("bgcolor");
        var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"))
        function SaveFon() {
                localStorage.setItem("object", fon)                                     
                localStorage.setItem("object2", colorVal)
            }               
        function changebodycolor(){
            colorVal = colorPicker.value;
            document.body.style.background = colorVal;
            fon = 3;
            SaveFon();  
        }                   

        colorPicker.addEventListener("change",
        changebodycolor,false);
    </script>
```

И условие:

```
var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"))
var colorVal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object2"))

 if (retObj == "2") {
    document.body.classList.add('winter');
} else if (retObj == "3") {
    document.body.style.background = colorVal;
} else if (retObj == "4") { }
```

Т.е. если фоном выбрана картинка (в коде нет, это на др странице), то переменной присваивается значение "`2`", далее эта переменная записывается в `LS` и вынимается в файле `JS`, который Вы видите. Всё работает с этой переменной отлично и таким образом меняя фон на одной странице он меняется на всех даже если пользователь покинет сайт и вернется потом - благодаря `LS`. Но есть небольшая проблема с установкой цвета фона. Реализацию Вы видите выше. Я сохраняю переменную `colorVal` и вынимаю в файле `JS`, где использую вот так:

```
 document.body.style.background = colorVal;
```

Но, увы, фон не сохраняется. Почему? Переменная такого типа не может запомнится в `LS` или я что-то делаю не так? Кстати, условие выполняется, т.е. переменная `retObj` равна "`3`", это я проверял. Дело именно в `colorVal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Консоль показывает ошибку

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 at
>   JSON.parse

при этом ссылается на строку:

```
var colorVal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object2"))
```

Уберите `JSON.parse()` и всё будет норм работать.

Comment: Да, цвет стал сохранятся, но почему-то вне зависимости какой я выберу, сохранится он как бежевый. Т.е. выберу синий - вижу синий фон, всё отлично. Обновлю страницу - а фон бежевый.

Comment: проблема решена, спасибо!

Comment: Не подскажите, то же самое, но с градиентом: https://jsfiddle.net/pzy4vjam/1/

вроде сохраняю переменную gradient, однако не сохраняется фон..

Comment: Сделайте полноценный пример с нужным HTML.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pzy4vjam/2/

Comment: nice try, но теперь сделайте все же пример без ошибок в консоли для начала )

Comment: ну там три ошибки были не связаны, но да ладно, убрал) https://jsfiddle.net/pzy4vjam/3/

Comment: Вот, забыл: https://jsfiddle.net/pzy4vjam/4/

Comment: У меня к вам две рекомендации: разобраться с понятием "область видимости" и дебажить ваш код при помощи Developer Tools, там же можно и смотреть что в localStorage записывается. Сейчас дело в том, что вы вызываете функцию `saveFon()`, которая записывает в LS некую переменную `gradient`, которая объявляется внутри функции `doIt.onclick = function(){}` — и в итоге там нечего записывать. Также у вас прямо сразу `fon = 6`, осторожнее с таким обращением с переменными в яваскрипте )

Comment: Подождите.. вот именно, что переменная gradient объявляется и после сохраняется функцией SaveFon(). Также и переменная fon = 6, поэтому в условии должно выполняется: document.body.style.background = gradient;, а сохраненный gradient я заранее уже вынул.

И в чем опасность такого обращения?)